# Flapping interface on a Windows Cluster

Tags: windows

There is a Windows Cluster 2008r2 which has a resource group with an IP address/interface in it.

problem: the interface flaps. sometimes it will go down and up.

**Question**: What could possibly cause an interface to flap?

If any further info needed, please ask.

Comment: have yo check your windows event log?

Comment: yes, but only contains info about link down